# How to access variables in a class with a function in the same class in python?

Tags: python, list, class

So I'm doing a economy simulation but I'm just testing right now and I need to create a class for the jobs

```
class job:
    name = 'Temp'
    money = 0
    price = 0
    needs = []
    amount = 0
    def sell(self, amount, money, price):
        amount -= 1
        money += price
    def buy(self, needs):
        for x in len(needs):
        needs(x).buy()

Farmer = job()
Miner = job()
Farmer.price = 15
Farmer.needs.append("Miner")
Farmer.amount = 1
Farmer.name = 'Farmer'
Farmer.money = 0

Miner.price = 15
Miner.needs.append("Farmer")
Miner.amount = 1
Miner.name = 'Miner'
Miner.money = 0

Miner.buy()
```

So what I want to do is change the needs in the code, then every update (not implemented yet) they'll buy from their needs and the person they buy from gets the money. I know the code is probably horrible. But I'm pretty new

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, but I think you need `needs` to be an [instance variable rather than a class variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables), and an `__init__` method that defines `self.needs = []` when you create a new instance of `job`.

Comment: I suggest that you define you function by as def buy(self, Provider) where provider is an instance of job. eg. **Miner.buy(Farmer)**